# How to feed series data that has x axis and y axis values in line highcharts?

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts

I have to show some results of an experiment in a line chart. I got it working for static data, but I want to make it dynamic.

So what I got:

I have a line charts:

```
       var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                        type: 'line',
                            },
                    series: [{}]
        }
```

I want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/data-array-of-arrays/

I am struggling to make those data:

```
            data: [
            [0, 29.9], 
            [1, 71.5], 
            [3, 106.4]
        ]
```

in php side and send it jquery, and feed to my line chart. 
I am aware of JSON encoding, but how should I create and array in php in first place? 
And how should I encode it and give it to jquery and feed my line chart?

This is working so far with static data:

```
             var arr = [[0, 15], [10, 50], [20, 56.5], [30, 46.5], [40, 22.1],
                            [50, 2.5], [60, 27.7], [70, 55.7], [80, 76.5]];
                options.series[0].name = 'Occlusion';
                options.series[0].data = arr;
    var l = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
```

But I want arr to come from php.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906401/pass-array-to-javascript-as-array-not-json-from-php

Comment: but this is not exactly what I wanted to ask. the [[x1, y1],[x2, y2]] array I want to create in PHP and feed the series data in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create such format, you need to restructure them first. Consider this example:

```
<?php

// lets say you have a raw data like this
$php_values = array(
    array(0, 15),
    array(10, 50),
    array(20, 56.5),
    array(30, 46.5),
    array(40, 22.1),
    array(50, 2.5),
    array(60, 27.7),
    array(70, 55.7),
    array(80, 76.5),
);

$temp = array();
// format each array
foreach($php_values as $key => $value) {
    $temp[] = '['.implode(',', $value).']';
}
// then format the whole array
$formatted_values = '['.implode(',', $temp).']';

?>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var values = <?php echo $formatted_values; ?>;
    console.log(values);

</script>
```

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/yftGET)

> Edit: as @SebastianBochan pointed out, **`$formatted_values = json_encode($php_array)`** works the same way (probably the best and cleanest way)

Comment: echo json_encode($php_values) will not be better, instead of using implode etc?

Comment: @SebastianBochan thanks for pointing that out, good alternative