# How to Pass PHP Array to Javascript as JSON Array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

Currently I am doing the POST Operation to PHP file from the Javascript to perform the operation in PHP and get the response, But in the php file I am having the Array and I wanted to receive it to JavaScript as JSON Array How Can I do that

**Java Script**

```
$scope.details = function() {
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'myjson.json'
  }).then(function(response) 
  })
```

**PHP Code**

```
 <?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');
// index.php
// Run the parallel get and print the total time
$s = microtime(true);
// Define the URLs
$urls = array(
  "url1",
  "url2",
  "url3"
);
$pg = new ParallelGet($urls);
//print "<br />total time: ".round(microtime(true) - $s, 4)." seconds";

// Class to run parallel GET requests and return the transfer
class ParallelGet
{
  function __construct($urls)
  {
    // Create get requests for each URL
    $mh = curl_multi_init();
    $headers = array(
    'authorization: Basic xyz',
    'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
    'Accept:application/json'
  );
    foreach($urls as $i => $url)
    {
      $ch[$i] = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
      curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch[$i]);
    }

    // Start performing the request
    do {
        $execReturnValue = curl_multi_exec($mh, $runningHandles);
    } while ($execReturnValue == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    // Loop and continue processing the request
    while ($runningHandles && $execReturnValue == CURLM_OK) {
      // Wait forever for network
      $numberReady = curl_multi_select($mh);
      if ($numberReady != -1) {
        // Pull in any new data, or at least handle timeouts
        do {
          $execReturnValue = curl_multi_exec($mh, $runningHandles);
        } while ($execReturnValue == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
      }
    }

    // Check for any errors
    if ($execReturnValue != CURLM_OK) {
      trigger_error("Curl multi read error $execReturnValue\n", E_USER_WARNING);
    }

    // Extract the content
    foreach($urls as $i => $url)
    {
      // Check for errors
      $curlError = curl_error($ch[$i]);
      if($curlError == "") {
        $res[$i] = curl_multi_getcontent($ch[$i]);
        //$finalResponse[] = $res[$i]->load();
      } else {
        print "Curl error on handle $i: $curlError\n";
      }
      // Remove and close the handle
      curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch[$i]);
      curl_close($ch[$i]);

    }
    // Clean up the curl_multi handle
    curl_multi_close($mh);
      //print_r($res);
    $responseArray = $res;
    // Print the response data

  $responseMSO = json_encode($res);
//print_r(utf8_encode(json_encode($res)));
  //echo $finalResponse[1];
  //echo $responseMSO;
  }

}
?>
```

Now I want to send these to Javascript as JSONArray

I have seen the suggestion to use json_encode in PHP but when I use that I am getting response as utf-encoded.

Any one please help here

I have referred all the below but didn't help much

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906401/pass-array-to-javascript-as-array-not-json-from-php)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23305636/pass-php-array-to-javascript-array)

Comment: _"I am getting response as utf-encoded"_ and why is that a problem? Are you using some other type of encoding?

Comment: It's just `echo json_encode($myarray)` in your PHP

Comment: can you show us the code through  which you are getting this `$myarray`

Comment: Hi Batman. your json format was wrong. Please copy and paste json data into this url to check your json data https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: I have made my json very simplied to make it easy. I will put the way its showing when I am using json_encode

Comment: `["{\"status\":{\"1\":{\"id\":1,\"color\":\"#75B000\",\"description\":\"Test was executed and passed successfully.\"` I am getting this for each I am getting \ symbol not sure why. Where As I should be getting only `["{"status":{"1":{"id":1,"color":"#75B000","descr‌iption":"Test was executed and passed successfully."`

Comment: @All I have updated my PHP Code(Here I am doing multi curl operation to get the response from  multiple GET operation in parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 

$myarray = array('{ "name":"中", "age":30, "car":null }','{ "name":"Mike", "age":32, "car":null }');
foreach ($myarray as $array) {
    $arrays[] = json_decode($array);
}

echo json_encode($arrays, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
echo '<br>';
echo json_encode($arrays);

?>
```

As you can see the first sample has unescaped unicode

OUTPUT:

[{"name":"中","age":30,"car":null},{"name":"Mike","age":32,"car":null}]
[{"name":"\u4e2d","age":30,"car":null},{"name":"Mike","age":32,"car":null}]

Comment: Okay Micheal let me try and update you thanks..I am issue with server now will test and update back once it is up..

Comment: I have tried this but , In the JS Console I am getting proper response
`{"status":{"1":{"id":1,"color":"#75B000","description":"Test was executed and passed successfully.","name":"PASS"}` But When Just run the standalone PHP page I am getting

`["{\"status\":{\"1\":{\"id\":1,\"color\":\"#75B000\",\"description\":\"Test was executed and passed successfully.\",\"name\":\"PASS\"},`

Comment: Seems like your curl_multi_getcontent($ch[$i]) is already in json format. Convert that to array first to avoid double encoding http://www.phpwin.org/s/J2LabK

Comment: Perfect thanks for really making understand with this example :)

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to send these to Javascript as JSONArray like below

`[{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null },{ "name":"Mike", "age":32, "car":null }]`

OK so set up php array first:

```
$myarray = array(
        array(
            'name' => 'John',
            'age'  => 30,
            'car'  => null
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Mike',
            'age'  => 32,
            'car'  => null
        )
);
```

then json encode it in php

```
echo  json_encode($myarray);
```

Result:`[{"name":"John","age":30,"car":null},{"name":"Mike","age":32,"car":null}]`

For more details on proper way to send a json response from php using json take a look at this: [Returning JSON from a PHP Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script)

Comment: ["{\"status\":{\"1\":{\"id\":1,\"color\":\"#75B000\",\"descr‌​iption\":\"Test was executed and passed successfully.\" I am getting this for each I am getting \ symbol not sure why. Where As I should be getting only ["{"status":{"1":{"id":1,"color":"#75B000","descr‌iption":"T‌​est was executed and passed successfully."

Comment: in `json_encode` pass in a second param `json_encode($myarray, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)`

Comment: I have tried this but , In the JS Console I am getting proper response `{"status":{"1":{"id":1,"color":"#75B000","description":"Test was executed and passed successfully.","name":"PASS"}` But When Just run the standalone PHP page I am getting `["{\"status\":{\"1\":{\"id\":1,\"color\":\"#75B000\",\"descr‌​iption\":\"Test was executed and passed successfully.\",\"name\":\"PASS\"},`

Comment: create a phpfiddle to see what you are doing

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to convert an array of objects in PHP and have it JSON-encoded so that JavaScript can use the result, here's one way to accomplish that feat:

```
<?php


$o = new stdClass;
$o->name = "John";
$o->age = 30;
$o->car =null;

$o2 = new stdClass;
$o2->name = "Mike";
$o2->age = 32;
$o2->car =null;

$myarray = [$o, $o2];

var_dump(json_encode($myarray));

// result:
 "[{"name":"John","age":30,"car":null},{"name":"Mike","age":32,"car":null}]"
```

see example [here](https://3v4l.org/8Fcn5).

For the json-encoded PHP array of objects to be useful for JavaScript it needs to be enclosed in single quotes and then parsed with JSON, as follows:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var obj = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($myarray) ?>');
console.log(obj[0].name + "\t" + obj[1].name); // John   Mike
</script>
```

See useful resource [here](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/parse.php) and this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040794/how-to-access-json-encoded-data-of-an-array-using-javascript).

Comment: ["{\"status\":{\"1\":{\"id\":1,\"color\":\"#75B000\",\"descr‌​iption\":\"Test was executed and passed successfully.\" I am getting this for each I am getting \ symbol not sure why. Where As I should be getting only ["{"status":{"1":{"id":1,"color":"#75B000","descr‌iption":"T‌​est was executed and passed successfully."

Comment: @Batman please take a look at my updated example code with respect to how to use the json-encoded PHP array of objects in JavaScript; this should now work for you.